# Loop: Find string based on list and adjust trailing zeros and around border in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, zero, trailing

Summary: Find text/string based on list in another sheet and adjust trailing zeros with border around the range.

The excel workbook containing two sheet.
Sheet1 Name: List (having column A with text/string to be find and column B having numerical value) as in first image.

Sheet2 Name: "Raw" containing text anywhere and below numerical value with different decimal points. Also having few blank rows between set of range as in image 2.

I have recorded macro and tried to edit it. This macro working for Text1. Below macro find text1 in "raw" sheet and adjust the display of trailing zeros based on B1 value of list sheet.

How to loop the all listed text in column A of sheet list and adjust display of trailing zeros with outside borders. Output in image 3. Find as xlpart.

Sheet1 or list

[image: List]

Sheet2 or another sheet

[image: Raw Data]

Output

[image: Output]

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim sFirstAddress As String
Dim rng As Excel.Range


 With Sheets("Raw").Range("A1:DZ1000") '.UsedRange ???
'how to loop for list of text/string present in column A as in image 1.

 Set C = .Find(What:="Text1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, _
    SearchFormat:=False)
If Not C Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = C.Address
    Do

Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

'how to loop for number in column B for adjusting/Keeping trailing zero's

If Sheets("List").Range("B1") = 1 Then
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Else
If Sheets("List").Range("B1") = 2 Then
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Else
If Sheets("List").Range("B1") = 3 Then
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"

End If
End If
End If

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate


Set C = .FindNext(C)
    If C Is Nothing Then
        GoTo DoneFinding
    End If
    Loop While C.Address <> FirstAddress
  End If
DoneFinding:
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to loop the all listed text in column A of sheet list to be find in "raw" sheet and adjust display of trailing zeros based on value present in column B. In addition, outside border to cell of find text and range of number value as in image 3.

Comment: Question edited and comments added in code.

Comment: You've posted some code so what's the problem with it?

Comment: I don't know how to loop both columns of sheet list in above macro to find all text and adjust trailing zeros in sheet "Raw"

Answer (score 0):

By doing trial and error continuously for 6 hours, I am able to loop both columns of list sheet and output as expected. Below code working perfectly.

```
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MySearch As Variant
Dim myColor As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim I As Long

Dim item As Range




For Each item In Sheets("List").UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

MySearch = Array(item.Value2)
If item.Value2 = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else

With Sheets("Raw").UsedRange 'Range("B1:AA10000")


   For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)



        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)


        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address

            Do
                    With Rng.Borders
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Weight = xlThin
                        .ColorIndex = 0
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With


                   Rng.Offset(1, 0).Select

                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    If item.Offset(, 1).Value2 = 1 Then
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"

                        Else
                    If item.Offset(, 1).Value2 = 2 Then
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

                        Else
                    If item.Offset(, 1).Value2 = 3 Then
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"

                    Else
                    If item.Offset(, 1).Value2 = 4 Then
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
                        End If
                        End If
                        End If
                    End If



                    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)


            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress

       End If

    Next I
End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```